# BSpline interpolation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, spline

For a project in school we have to write a function in Matlab.

[c] = spline_coeff(x,f)
where 
• x vector of interpolation points; 
• f vector of function values ;
• c vector of coefficienten from de interpolating cubic splinefunction.

We have tried loads of algorithms we have found online, but nothing works.
Can anyone push us in the right direction, or provide us with some example data and solutions of that data. Because that is imposible to find online also.

Thanks

Comment: "Nothing works" can't be hardly true. Pick any approach you like and post what you have tried.

Comment: Just the values of the function at each of the support points is not enough to define the coefficients for your cubic spline. For $n+1$ points, you will have $4n$ coefficients to find, but matching the point values and the slopes only gives you $3n-1$ equations defining the coefficients. How you get the other $n + 1$ equations is the difference between the various methods. One that I learned (but do not find mentioned on the wikipedia page) is to also match the 2nd derivatives (another $n-1$ equations) and specify the slopes at the first and last points to get the remaining 2 equations.